# Git date of commit older than main repository

Tags: git, python-3.x, logging, author

could someone help me please with confusing about Git dates? I write Python script to extract info about repository from **git log**. During testing on big Linux repository (https://github.com/torvalds/linux) I use **author date** --pretty="%at" as timestamp and in Python convert into human readable string with

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( timestamp ).strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
```

Result looks fine but generate two strange dates from all in this repo:

```
2001-09-17 09:00:00 aebda618718157a69c0dc0adb978d69bc2b8723c
2001-09-17 09:00:00 dbe79bbe9dcb22cb3651c46f18943477141ca452
```

As info https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux says, repo was "created_at": "2011-09-04T22:48:12Z" and I do not know how it is possible? Commit is older than repo.

In CMD only with **git log** I checked output too and got same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamps in a Git commit are up to the user.

The *default* is to use the computer's current clock setting, which is ... up to the user.

Commit `aebda618718157a69c0dc0adb978d69bc2b8723c` in a Linux repository is this one:

```
commit aebda618718157a69c0dc0adb978d69bc2b8723c
Author:     John Youn <John.Youn synopsys.com>
AuthorDate: Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001 -0700
Commit:     Felipe Balbi <balbi ti.com>
CommitDate: Wed Jul 22 08:52:42 2015 -0500

    usb: dwc3: Reset the transfer resource index on SET_INTERFACE

    This fixes an issue introduced in commit b23c843992b6 (usb: dwc3:
    gadget: fix DEPSTARTCFG for non-EP0 EPs) that made sure we would
    only use DEPSTARTCFG once per SetConfig.
[snip]
```

which as you can see was authored by John Youn and committed by Felipe Balbi.  Probably John Youn's computer's date was wrong at the time, and the 2015 date is likely correct.  We cannot know for sure; all we know is what the stored timestamp is, not why it is that particular value.

Note that commit `dbe79bbe9dcb22cb3651c46f18943477141ca452` also lists John Youn as its author.  He has a number of other commits with seemingly-correct dates, so it's hard to be sure, but perhaps his computer's clock was failing at some point.

Comment: Thank's for reply, I understand now. For generating statistic it's probably good point, cause if user check every commit date with repo creation date and significant part from all commit counts would be older than repo creation date, otput statistic could be very incorrect. In this example two commits are nothing against amount of 700k all commits